# How do I create a code for a custom variable in GTM to track the title of a click?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to pull the card's title when a user clicks on it. GTM is not pulling this information automatically, so I believe a Custom JavaScript Variable would be the best option.

This is the code of the page I want to track. I want to get the "Health Coaching" string.

```
<div c-cardservice_cardservice="" class="content">
  <a c-cardservice_cardservice="" class="title" title="Health Coaching" aria-label="Health Coaching" href="javascript:void(0);">Health Coaching</a>
</div>
```

I have tried a few combinations of code, but I'm very new to JavaScript, so I am figuring out what could be wrong. This is the last combination I tried, and it just returns the two brackets.

```
function () {
  el = document.querySelectorAll('div.content a.title[title]');
  return el;
}
```

What wrong with my code?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your function returns a NodeList, but you need a text content.

[Tesing function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMs7G.png)

Here is the correct function:

```js
function () {
  return document.querySelector("body > div.content > a").textContent;
}
```

P.s. You can also use Built-in variable in GTM `{{Click Text}}`. Sometimes it works correctly, but sometimes not. It depends from the hierarchy of the button the user is clicking.